# How to Handle WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException?

Tags: service, exchangewebservices

I have a Windows Service that access a mailbox periodically to process new emails via `EWS`.

After having it up and running for several days, it hit the following error, causing the service to stop. *(something like Exchange Service not available)*

I am still investigating if the error is just be temporary as I am still in development environment that is shared with other teams who might be doing some implementation which caused this error.

---

**Question:** May I know if the best way to handle this is to use a `try-catch`, where the `catch` will run the `GetNewEmail` method again in my main program?

---

Below is my code snippet:

```
List<EmailMessage> emailList = GetNewEmail(category);

public static List<EmailMessage> GetNewEmail(string folderName)
{
    FindItemsResults<Item> emailItemList;
    List<EmailMessage> retrievedEmailList = new List<EmailMessage>();
    int offset = 0;
    bool MoreItems = true;
    const int pageSize = 9999;

    if (service != null)
    {
        try
        {
            InitExchangeService();

            SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
            FolderView fView = new FolderView(1000);
            fView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;

            //error hit at the following line
            FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(
                WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
                new FolderView(int.MaxValue) { Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep });

            if (findFolderResults.Folders.Count == 0)
            {
                AppLogger.LogInfo("No folders found in Inbox.");
                return retrievedEmailList;
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder folder in findFolderResults.Folders)
                {
                    if (folder.DisplayName == folderName)
                    {
                        while (MoreItems)
                        {
                            ItemView view = new ItemView(pageSize, offset, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);
                            emailItemList = service.FindItems(folder.Id, sf, view);

                            foreach (var emailItem in emailItemList.Items)
                            {
                                EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, emailItem.Id);
                                retrievedEmailList.Add((EmailMessage)email);
                            }

                            if (!emailItemList.MoreAvailable)
                                MoreItems = false;

                            if (MoreItems)
                                offset += pageSize;
                        }
                        return retrievedEmailList;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppLogger.LogError(ex, "");
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return retrievedEmailList;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the EWS Managed API is a client library anytime you use a Method that will send a Request to the Exchange server you should have a Try Catch block around that code. Errors can come from Client (eg Network, DNS, local client issue) or from the Server as either a generic 501 type error or where you receive a SOAP response with a underlying Service Response Error code like Throttling (ServerBusy) which has a backoff you need to process. So if you writing resilient code you handler should be looking for and dealing with each of these exception differently (although most will just need a retry but the interval of the retry may need to change if your getting throttled or in Office365 if the Mailbox is being moved between data-centers and is temporarily unavailable etc).